# SSAS 2012 Measure FormatString not reflected in Excel Pivot Table

Tags: excel, ssas, pivot-table, excel-2016, ssas-2012

We have been successfully using the SSAS 2012 Measure FormatString property for several years.  We recently setup an additional server (SSAS Version 11.2.5058) and when connecting to a SSAS Cube on the new server via an Excel PivotTable the FormatString on the measure is no longer applied.  Our users now have to format the numbers every time they pull in a new cube.

**Additional Details:**

1. EXCEL Version = 2016
2. Cube Connection Properties (Number Format is selected)
   [Click to see properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGPhh.png)
3. Measure Format String configuration -- "#,##0.00;-#,##0.00" (note several standard and custom format strings were attempted).
   [Click to see configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hA7fI.png)
4. SSAS Versions:
   -- on the server that works correctly: 11.1.3000.0
   -- on the server that is not working correctly: 11.2.5058.0

Does anyone know if there is an issue with the FormatString property for SSAS Cube measures in version 11.2.5058.0?

Comment: Are there any scope statements in the Calculations tab that are changing the numbers in the cells which are the problem?

Comment: Can you install http://olappivottableextend.codeplex.com and then capture the MDX query that Excel is running. Please include in the thread. And please run that query in SSMS in an MDX window. Then double click a cell which is a problem in Excel and see what properties it retrieved in the popup window. I assume it is retrieving the proper FORMAT_STRING value. Don't worry if SSMS doesn't show the numbers as formatted. That's expected since Excel retrieves the VALUE and FORMAT_STRING properties then does the formatting itself.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I will post the actual MDX that is generated when connecting to the two production servers later today.

Comment: Please hold off on further research/analysis.  This may be related to an issue with the Excel file down from the web application.  The web application uses EPPLUS to set some document properties. Pulling the  cube into the downloaded Excel file ignores the format string.  Pulling the cube into an Excel file that was not manipulated by EPPLUS works correctly.  Once I fully understand and resolve this issue I will delete this question as it will likely not help anyone in the future.  I will also re-post a more accurate description of the issue with the solution.